# Extrapolate data points from a series of averages

Tags: statistics, average, data-analysis, extrapolation

Given a series of data points:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Monday} & \text{Tuesday} & \text{Wednesday} & \text{Thursday} & \text{Friday} & \text{Saturday} & \text{Sunday} \\ \hline
\text{Data Points} & 34 & 38&52&12&54&22&33 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I can compute mean averages:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{M-W} & \text{T-Th} & \text{W-F} & \text{Th-S} & \text{F-Su} \\ \hline
\text{Data Points} & 41.33 & 34.00 & 39.33 & 29.33 & 36.33 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Now say I only have the series of averages.

Two questions:

1. I think it is impossible to extrapolate the individual data points. Is there a proof of this?
2. Is it possible to extrapolate *possible ranges* for the individual data points? If so, how?

**Edit:** Assume all data points are in the range 0-100.

Comment: @NormalHuman I'm not sure which branch of mathematics would address this. Do you have a specific tag suggestion?

Comment: Does "Monday" mean _every_ Monday (so that the day after Sunday would have the same Monday average that is reported here) or just _one_ Monday (so that next Monday's average would be different)? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Just one Monday's average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table of averages gives $5$ linear equations in $7$ unknowns.
It is unlikely that you can recover the data points from the averages.

Indeed, the general solution can be expressed in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$:
\begin{align}
x_3 &=-x_1-x_2+124\\
x_4 &=x_1-22\\
x_5 &=x_2+16\\
x_6 &=-x_1-x_2+94\\
x_7 &=x_1-1
\end{align}
where I've used fractions for the averages, that is, $124/3$ instead of $41.33$.

If you have limits for the ranges of $x_1$ and $x_2$, then these equations give you limits for the ranges of the other variables.

Comment: @OP: As a (simpler than your actual values, but for the sake of the illustration) example, consider the following two sets of 7 values (for the days): $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$ and $(0,1,2,0,1,2,0)$. What are the corresponding $5$ mean averages, in both cases?

Comment: @ClementC. Right, but from the 5 mean averages (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), you know that 3 cannot be a data point (assuming all data points are non-negative). So a known range of 0-2 in this case.

Comment: If you know that the values cannot be negative, indeed. But you need an assumption like that.

Comment: @ClementC. So in the case of the 39.33 mean, I know the data points must be in the range 0-78.66. Can I narrow it down more than that?

Comment: Not necessarily 78.66. See the answer above (my comment was just addressing 1). with a simple counterexample)

Comment: @lhf Can you please explain how you calculated $22$ in the equation $x_4 = x_1 - 22$? (Or how you'd get it without knowing the original data points.)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: $(41.33*3)-(34*3)$. Thanks for a great answer!